# kendo masked text box mask change does not work

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I tried one of the example given on the `MaskedTextBox` component page but while assigning the mask or rules on `ngOnInit`, it gives error :

```
 Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 
                              'undefined'. Current value: '__ ___'
```

How to achieve changing mask property on the fly?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 
    <kendo-maskedtextbox
    name="value1"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [mask]="mask"></kendo-maskedtextbox>
})
export class AppComponent {
    public value: string;
    public mask: string;
    public maskValidation: boolean = true;
ngOnInit(){
    this.mask = "99 999";
    }
}
```

**Attached plunker:**

[Kendo Masked Text Box](http://plnkr.co/edit/nCvHtWgkrqr0KkYiXArQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug to me. You should definitely open an issue in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues).